# WP Update plugin DB table

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am building a plugin which on activation and deactivation will create and remove the database, this works fine.

Where the issue is when I try to create an update for the DB table it errors and breaks.

I have a class file called class WIP_Forecast and below is my update function inside my Class.

I am pretty new to plugin building and would really like some help fixing this issue.

```
global $wip_forecast_db_version, $current_version;

$wip_forecast_db_version = '1.1';
$get_current_version = get_option('wip_forecast_db_version');

class WIP_Forecast
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // register actions
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'update_db_checker' );            
    }

    public static function activate(){
    // Works
    }
....
    /**
     * Update Plugin DB
     */
    function update_db_checker()
    {
        if ( $get_current_version != $wip_forecast_db_version ) {
            wip_forecast_updates($wip_forecast_db_version);
        }
    }

    function wip_forecast_updates($wip_forecast_db_version)
    {           
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wip_forecast';

        if ($get_current_version === 1.1)
        {
            $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE $table_name ADD COLUMN `count` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL");
        } else if ($get_current_version === 1.2){
            //$wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE $table_name ADD COLUMN `count` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL");
        }else{
            //Do Nothing
        }

        update_option('wip_forecast_db_version', $wip_forecast_db_version);
    }
...
    public static function deactivate(){
    // Works
    }
}
if(class_exists('WIP_Forecast'))
{
    // Installation and uninstallation hooks
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('WIP_Forecast', 'activate'));
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wip_forecast_create_db' );

    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array('WIP_Forecast', 'deactivate'));

    // instantiate the plugin class
    $wip_forecast = new WIP_Forecast();
}
```

Comment: and what error would that be? you need to take that into account as well

Comment: The error I am getting is: PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'check_plugin_db_version' not found or invalid function name in .../class-wp-hook.php on line 287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global $wip_forecast_db_version, $get_current_version;

class WIP_Forecast
{
private $wip_forecast_db_version;
private $get_current_version;

public function __construct()
{
    $wip_forecast_db_version = '1.1';
    $get_current_version = get_option('wip_forecast_db_version');

    // register actions
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'update_db_checker' );
}
}
```